# How to properly define roles and privileges (Case study - PostgreSQL)?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, roles, privileges

A while ago I came here in the community to ask about the definition of a trigger for a system that I am developing. I still find myself developing the same system, and now I have doubts about roles. I'm new to using PostgreSQL, and even following the documentation, I end up with some questions.

For the development of my system I created 3 users:

- dbadiretor (translated to dbadirector): It behaves as DBA, and is used by only one person.
- dbagerente (translated to dbamanager): It is a user able to change table structures without
  manipulating it's data. This same user is also able to create
  triggers, functions, indexes, and the like.
- clisistema (translated to clisystem): It is the system with
  connection to the database. This user can perform CRUD operations,
  but can not create, delete, modify, or remove existing objects in
  database. For some tables, this user has its privileges filtered.

After creating users, tables, simple data, and set privileges, pgAdmin is showing me the following message:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation tb_tabelas
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "regrast"."tb_tabelas" x WHERE "tab_id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"

********** Error **********

ERROR: permission denied for relation tb_tabelas
SQL state: 42501
Context: SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "regrast"."tb_tabelas" x WHERE "tab_id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
```

I'm using postgres user, and I do not know what I'm doing wrong. I'm not making these statements (at least not directly):

```
"SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "regrast"."tb_tabelas" x WHERE "tab_id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
```

Here is the creation of my users:

```
-- DROP OWNED BY dbadiretor CASCADE;    
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS dbadiretor; 
CREATE ROLE dbadiretor WITH     
    SUPERUSER                   
    CREATEDB                    
    CREATEROLE                  
    LOGIN                       
    REPLICATION             
    CONNECTION LIMIT 1  
    PASSWORD 'dbadiretor';  

-- DROP OWNED BY dbagerente CASCADE;    
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS dbagerente;     
CREATE ROLE dbagerente WITH     
    NOSUPERUSER                 
    NOCREATEDB                  
    NOCREATEROLE            
    NOINHERIT                   
    LOGIN                   
    NOREPLICATION       
    CONNECTION LIMIT 3  
    PASSWORD 'dbagerente';  

-- DROP OWNED BY clisistema CASCADE;
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS clisistema; 
CREATE ROLE clisistema WITH 
    NOSUPERUSER                 
    NOCREATEDB                  
    NOCREATEROLE                
    NOINHERIT                   
    LOGIN                       
    NOREPLICATION                   
    CONNECTION LIMIT 30             
    PASSWORD '12345';
```

And here is the distribution of privileges:

```
-- #####################################
--  USUÁRIO: PUBLIC
-- #####################################

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "ELocadora" FROM PUBLIC;

-- #####################################
--  USUÁRIO: dbadiretor
-- #####################################

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA regrast TO dbadiretor;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "ELocadora" TO dbadiretor;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA regrast TO dbadiretor;

-- #####################################
--  USUÁRIO: clisistema
-- #####################################

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "ELocadora" TO clisistema;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA regrast TO clisistema;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA regrast TO clisistema;

-- NÍVEL DE FILTRO 1

REVOKE TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA regrast FROM clisistema;
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA regrast FROM clisistema;
REVOKE TEMP ON DATABASE "ELocadora" FROM clisistema;

-- NÍVEL DE FILTRO 2

-- Tabela: TB_TABELAS
-- Revogação: CUD
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE regrast.tb_tabelas FROM clisistema;

-- Tabela: TB_DADOS
-- Revogação: CUD
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE regrast.tb_dados FROM clisistema;

-- Tabela: TB_MODIFICACOES
-- Revogação: CUD
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE regrast.tb_modificacoes FROM clisistema;

-- Tabela: TB_TIPOS_DE_LOGS
-- Revogação: CUD
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE regrast.tb_tipos_de_logs FROM clisistema;

-- Tabela: TB_LOGS
-- Revogação: CUD
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE regrast.tb_logs FROM clisistema;

-- Tabela: TB_HISTORICO_DE_PRODUTOS
-- Revogação: CUD
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE regrast.tb_historico_de_produtos FROM clisistema;

-- Tabela: TB_CONFIGURACOES
-- Revogação: CD
REVOKE INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE regrast.tb_configuracoes FROM clisistema;

-- #####################################
--  USUÁRIO: dbagerente
-- #####################################

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "ELocadora" TO dbagerente;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA regrast TO dbagerente;
REVOKE INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA regrast FROM dbagerente;
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA regrast TO dbagerente;
GRANT REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA regrast TO dbagerente;
```

I was reading in the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html) that I need to set an appropriate owner for tables if I wish to modify them in any way. For example, regarding CREATE privilege:

> CREATE
>
> For schemas, allows new objects to be created within the schema. **To
>   rename an existing object, you must own the object** ***and*** have this
>   privilege for the containing schema.

So, all my tables have the dbagerente user as owner. As dbagerente, I can modify structures. But as dbadiretor or postgres, I can not, and that's not what I want. For me, the dbadiretor and postgres are superusers, they should be able to accomplish anything... Or not? :/

Looking a little further ahead... Must I watch out *be careful) for other database objects such as functions, triggers, etc.?

**Note**: I'm using PostgreSQL **9.5**, with a database named ELocadora, and a schema named regrast.

---

Out this presented problem, if possible (if you dont mind), would you have any recommendations for the proper distribution of roles for a beginner like me? Any link or tip could help me.

Moreover, is there any contraindications to create a new user only for the realization of logs? A system transaction (for some operations) may end up having to use two types of users to complete.

Thank you for your attention eitherway.

### EDIT

> I'm suspecting that this error is showing up due to the dependencies
>   between tables. In certain tables for certain foreign keys, I'm using
>   ON DELETE and ON UPDATE statements.
>
> When entering data a first time, the data is entered without problem.
>   However, if I delete them to reinsert them, this error appears.
>
> Is there something to do with this?

I was wrong, this information is unfounded. Disregard it, please. And I'm sorry.

### EDIT 2

I recorded all the process, with all the steps and apparent problems. Everything made from scratch. Please, take a look (4 min):

[Here](http://sendvid.com/30c2s87s)

The SQL files that are open represent different operations being made. They are organized in different steps. Again, what I'm doing wrong?

### EDIT 3

I found a small bug in my code. Non-destructive (initially). Inside the records insertion code, I changed this:

```
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('ID' , 'USU_ID' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%'));
```

Into this:

```
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('ID' , 'USU_ID' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
```

> @Chris Travers
>
> [...] and therefore the table owner must have write access to the
>   cascading table before anyone can delete from them.
>
> [...] So the issue here is that the table owner doesn't have access.

But I'm using a super account. I mean, I'm using a super user. Theoretically, there are no restrictions here because I'm a super user, no? I as superuser'm trying to insert and remove tables records. And yet I'm getting this error.

Here is the following code that is giving me error:

```
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('ID' , 'USU_ID' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('Login' , 'USU_LOGIN' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('Senha' , 'USU_SENHA' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('Apelido' , 'USU_APELIDO' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('Nascimento' , 'USU_NASCIMENTO' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('Cadastro' , 'USU_CADASTRO' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('Gênero' , 'USU_GENERO' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('Privilégio' , 'USU_PRIVILEGIO' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('CEP' , 'USU_CEP' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('Número Residencial' , 'USU_NUMERO' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO regrast.TB_DADOS (DAD_NOME_VISUAL , DAD_NOME_COLUNA , DAD_TABELA) VALUES ('Complemento' , 'USU_COMPLEMENTO' , (SELECT tba_id FROM regrast.tb_tabelas WHERE tba_nome ILIKE 'tb_usu%' LIMIT 1));
```

If I comment this, everything works just fine.

Comment: Which user are you connecting in pgadmin? Are you connected as dbagerente or dbadirector?

Comment: Hi @Isilva. As I said earlier, I am using the default user of PostgreSQL, the `postgres` user. I also tried using the `dbadiretor` as superuser, but it still fails. All these details are on the question.

Comment: Hi @Isilva, I just edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Right.  You have a couple options regarding shared ability to alter a table.

1. You can make the dba user into a superuser (this bypasses permission checks for this user) or
2. You can create another role (`with INHERIT NOLOGIN`) assign ownership to that role, and grant that role to anyone needing to modify structures.  The reason to add those options is that this is not a login role but one that manages shared permissions.  Permissions granted to this role (and ownership as well!) get shared between all roles that this is granted to.

For the permission denied for the select user, you are using the dbagerente user?  If so that is expected since you revoked permission for this then.  If not which username are you using?

**EDIT**.  Note that RI triggers of this sort operate as the table owner, and therefore the table owner must have write access to the cascading table before anyone can delete from them.

You an test by (in a transaction that rolls back):

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
-- statements that are failing here
ROLLBACK;
```

So the issue here is that the table owner doesn't have access.  In my experience I had to add both select and delete privileges (you may need update if you have on update too) granted to the table owner.\

**EDIT2: How to reproduce**

```
 CREATE USER myuser;
```

Now log in as myuser:

```
 CREATE TABLE ctest1 (id int primary key);
 INSERT INTO ctest1 (id) SELECT generate_series(0, 10);
 CREATE TABLE ctest2 (id int references ctest1(id) on delete cascade);
 INSERT INTO ctest2 (id) SELECT generate_series(0, 10);
 REVOKE ALL ON ctest2 FROM myuser; -- nonsuperuser owner
```

Now log in as postgres (superuser):

```
 DELETE FROM ctest1 WHERE id = 4;
 -- throws the error
 GRANT DELETE ON ctest2 TO myuser;
 DELETE FROM ctest1 WHERE id = 4;
 -- throws the error
 GRANT SELECT ON ctest2 TO myuser;
 DELETE FROM ctest1 WHERE id = 4; -- success
```

Comment: Hi @Chris Travers. Thank you for answering. Hmm... Is there nothing wrong with my distribution of privileges? No Improper order of commands? Did I not use any wrong command, or distribute privileges that should not be distributed? Is there nothing causing conflict here? :(

Comment: Hi.  There may have been a couple sides to this.  I will amend my answer to cover the other side too

Comment: you mention using the postgres user.  Which postgres user?  postgres?  If so did you alter the user to make postgres not a superuser?

Comment: I'm trying to insert new data using 2 users: `postgres` and `dbadiretor`. As `dbadiretor` or `postgres`, I can not insert new data, and that's not what I want (hence the error message - PostgreSQL doesn't allow me). I would like that `dbagerente` can change, insert and delete objects in the database, but without being able to perform CRUD operations. On the other hand, I would like to insert new data with `postgres`, `dbadiretor` and `clisistema` users. The `clisistema` user may not modify, remove, and create objects in the database (functions, tables, etc.).

Comment: Postgres is by default a superuser and bypasses permission checks, so my guess is that you have other permissions changes that are not shown?

Comment: All my change/addition/removal code of privileges is there. That's all. Regarding your first suggestion, my `dbadiretor` user is already a superuser. Take a look at the code.

Comment: have you got the same responses in psql as pgadmin?

Comment: I just edit my question. Could you take a look, please?

Comment: reviewed and added to the answer.

Comment: One more edit. If you don't mind, can you take a look? I'm sorry if I'm bothering you... That's not what I want. I just want to solve this problem. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: BTW, I reproduced my scenario using a superuser.  In other words if the table is owned by a non-superuser who does not have the right to do the cascading operations, they still fail.